# Open new UIViewController using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, events, uiviewcontroller

Using **CoreGraphics**, I am able to get click location.

My requirement is to open different `UIViewController` base on clicks on different areas of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `UIViewController` base on location of your touch using one of the following:

1. Create it manually

   ```
   let controller = SubclassViewController()
   //prepare your view controller here
   ```
2. Instantiate controller from storyboard

   ```
   if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier") as? SubclassViewController {
       //prepare your view controller here
   }
   ```
3. Perform segue to new view controller

   ```
   performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier")
   ```

   Then prepare your view controller within `prepareForSegue:`

   ```
   if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? SubclassViewController {
       //prepare your controller here
   }
   ```

Depending on what your app is doing, you can either to push your new view controller or present it manually